# C# Android: Play sound on click

Tags: c#, android, button, audio

I want to play a sound if I click on a button. But it says:

`Error CS0103: The name 'MediaPlayer' does not exist in the current context!`

Greets

EDIT: Code: **[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cifY07e9)**

Comment: It's just a test code: http://pastebin.com/cifY07e9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `using Android.Media;` in your code.

Comment: It's C# Not Java So i use: Using Android.media.MediaPlayer

Comment: It doesn't work anyways :(

Comment: During coding! Or is that compile? i started 2 days ago ;P